# replace string using array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
abc1    abc2    abc3
abc4    abc5    abc6
abc7    abc8    abc9
```

using above csv file, load text by replacing the double quotes from the bellow sentence.
Sentence:

```
"" is going with "" to "" for something to know.
```

Expected out put is:

```
abc1 is going with abc2 to abc3 for something to know.
abc3 is going with abc5 to abc6 for something to know.
```

like this in javascript, php.

Code I have tried so far:

```
var s = 'Neque porro "" estqui "" dolorem';
var insert = [["a1", "b1"]["c1","d1"]];
console.log(insert);
var words = new Array();
words = s.split(" ");
console.log(words);
var count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < insert.length; j++) {
        if(words[i] == '""')
            s = s.replace(/""/, insert[j]);
    }
}
console.log(s);
```

Comment: In Javascript *and* PHP? Perhaps also Haskell, Perl or Assembler? Do you want fries with that? What have you tried to solve this, what's the issue in implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hurray I got the answer:
    reader.onload = function (e) {
                                    var sent = ''; var sentt = ''; var senttt = '';
                                    sent = $('#mixmsg').val();
                                    var quoteLength = (sent.match(/""/g) || []).length;
                                    var rowcells = [];
                                     rows = e.target.result.split("\n"); alert(rows);
                                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                                        rowcells.push(cells);
                                    }
                                    var rowcellso = rowcells.slice(0, -1);
                                    console.log(rowcellso);
                                    for (var ro = 0; ro < rowcellso.length; ro++) {
                                        for (var scol = 0; scol < quoteLength; scol++) {
                                               sent =  sent.replace(/""/,rowcellso[ro][scol]);
                                           console.log(rowcellso[ro][scol]);                                       
                                        } sentt +=sent+'\n'; sent= $('#mixmsg').val();
                                    } 
                                    $('#container').html(sentt);
                                }
```